# Java error when adding and creating zip files: The process cannot access the file

Tags: java, jar, zip, uri, nio

I made a Java program using Java ZipFileSystem (Java 8) to archive files into zip files. I thought it'd be simple and straightforward, but after running for a while, it craps out with "java.nio.file.FileSystemException". Code snippet below:

```
        ......
        fileName = fileName + "_";
        int zipFileNameMidPart;
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(sourceDir, getFilter(sourceDir)))
        {
          for(Path path : dirStream)
          {
            lastModified.setTimeInMillis(Files.getLastModifiedTime(path, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).toMillis());
            zipFileNameMidPart = fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("salesfaxes") ? lastModified.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1 : (lastModified.get(Calendar.MONTH)/3)+1;
            zipFileName = fileName+lastModified.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"_"+zipFileNameMidPart+".zip";
            zipFile = Paths.get(srcDirTmp, zipFileName);
            addToZipArchive(path, zipFile, !Files.exists(zipFile), tmpMoveDir);
            
            //Move archived file to the temp directory.
            currentBackupFile = tmpMoveDir.resolve(path.getFileName());
            logger.info("Moving "+path+" to "+currentBackupFile);
            Files.move(path, currentBackupFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
          }
        }//try
  
protected void addToZipArchive(Path fileToBeArchived, Path zipArchive, boolean create, Path tmpBackupDir) throws Exception
      {
        /* Define ZIP File System Properies in HashMap */    
        Map<String, String> zip_properties = new HashMap<>(); 
        /* set create to true if you want to create a new ZIP file */
        zip_properties.put("create", Boolean.toString(create));
        /* specify encoding to UTF-8 */
        zip_properties.put("encoding", "UTF-8");        
        /* Locate File on disk for creation */
        URI zip_disk = URI.create("jar:file:/" + zipArchive.toString().replace("\\", "/"));
        totalCnt++;
        /* Create ZIP file System */
        try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zip_disk, zip_properties)) 
        {
          /* Path inside ZIP File */
          Path pathInZipfile = zipfs.getPath(fileToBeArchived.getFileName().toString());
          boolean copyOk = true;
          try
          {
            logger.info("Adding "+fileToBeArchived.toString()+" to "+(create?"new ":"existing ")+"zip file "+zipArchive.toString());
                /* Add file to archive */
                Files.copy(fileToBeArchived, pathInZipfile, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING); 
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
                copyOk = false;
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
          }
          if(copyOk)
          {         
            if(create)
              createCnt++;
            else
              addCnt++;    
          }
          else
          {
            logger.severe("Skip file "+fileToBeArchived+"! Error encounted while archiving it.");
            skippedCnt++;
          }
        }
      }
```

Stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Error occured!
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\temp\bols\bols_2017_4.zip: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)
at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.sync(ZipFileSystem.java:1301)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.close(ZipFileSystem.java:277)
at ZipArchiveUtil.addToZipArchive(ZipArchiveUtil.java:177)
at ZipArchiveUtil.processDirs(ZipArchiveUtil.java:282)
at ZipArchiveUtil.main(ZipArchiveUtil.java:392)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:61)
```

The directories are quite large containing tens of thousands tif files. And zip files can also grow very large (exceed gigabyte in file sizes).
I've tried to run the program at night and weekend, still got same error after running for a while.
Also replicated the env on a different pc, same result.
Seems like the program is still holding on the zip file while trying to add new file into it... What am I missing? Did some googling, haven't found much info.

Another weird thing, from time to time the program "pauses", doing nothing. If I do CTRL Z, then it starts processing again. I checked in Task Manager, no CPU and disk usages while it's on "pause".

Any helps/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Close your files when done.

Comment: Are you referring to this line? `try (FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zip_disk, zip_properties))`. It a try-with-resources statement, meaning that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

Comment: It still looks like the file is not being closed.  Try a close and see if that does anything.

Comment: I'm a little lost... Could you please specify which file and where a close() statement should be added? Thanks.

Comment: I would put it after if( OK ){ ... } else {... }; zipfs.close();  ie. close the file after you are done using it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have to disagree. The try-with-resources statement is guaranteed to close resource, therefore calling close() isn't needed. I tried anyway, still got the same exception as expected after running for some time.

Comment: OK, what did you get in the 'logger' messages? Please show your logger output. Actually I got a little lost in your if – else  statements, please indent.  The close should have been  with the OK=false.

Comment: Same exception as I posted originally.